# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

In about two weeks, this community will receive some provisional moderators to help get this site started prior to the elections at the end of the beta. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

**Please suggest some members of this community you feel would make excellent moderators *(self nominations are okay).***

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: I just looked through the user list...just about everyone on it appears to be qualified to be a moderator...I'm actually impressed by this community in its first hours of existence.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, so far it is one of the most pleasant communities I've seen on SE.

Comment: We're running out of time, so we probably should start nominating for the temporary moderators.

Comment: I'd like to apply as a moderator, but then I'll have to refrain from mocking other users and having bad manners. :-(

Comment: @TomWij: this is all temporary anyway... I wouldn't get too hung up on it. If the site makes it out of Beta, they'll run actual *elections*, with something like this used purely to nominate candidates.

Comment: @TomWij: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-nominations/ and then http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/

Comment: @TomWij: "The I've been guilty..." comment is a great reason on its own to _not_ vote for you as a moderator...

Comment: @Tom: I haven't see anyone bashing you outside of this thread. In this thread, you've more than earned any bashing. Your completely out-of-proportion reaction to perceived insults should be enough by itself to remove you from contention for a moderator position at any site.

Comment: @TomWij, you're trying too hard. ;-)

Comment: Not sure it'd be worth it- the appointments are (theoretically) made about a week into public beta- that's come and gone.

Comment: @Dan Dyer (regarding your edit): I don't think it's the moderator's job to try to direct the direction of the site- that's the job of the community at large.  Based on what I've read in the SE blog articles, the moderator's role is just to organize the community decision-making process, keep the peace, and communicate with the SE powers that be.

Comment: @lorenzo "@Thomas: yes, so far it is one of the most pleasant communities I've seen on SE" my how the tables have turned, eh?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: Perhaps you should look again instead of exaggerating?

Comment: Post locked to prevent further tampering with the answers.

Answer (score 15):

**[ChrisF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47)** ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf))

I'd like to put myself forward as an extra or backup moderator. **I don't want to take the place of anyone else who's willing and able to do the job**, but I thought it might be useful if there was somebody who "knew the ropes" so to speak.

I'm already a moderator on the [Web Applications site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf) and I'm a 10K user on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf), [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/289/chrisf) and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) so I know how the system works.

Comment: I'll second (and upvote) that.  It would indeed be useful to have someone who's familiar with mod tools and practices.

Comment: +1 I like your experience, positive attitute and calm tones.

Answer (score 10):

#### [FishToaster](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/fishtoaster))

I'd like to throw my hat in, since the guidelines say self-nomination is encouraged.  No one's been here long enough to really establish their credentials, but we need people with mod tools, so here I am.  I've been reasonably active in both NPR and meta.NPR, and intend to be for a while (at the very least for the duration of the temporary modship).

Comment: I'll second (and upvote) your nomination.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how you gained 1,959 reputation in 7 days

Comment: @TheLQ - 106 answers might have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm neutral about your nomination; while I think it's great that you're extremely active and that level of activity is definitely an asset, I fear you might be a little too active to look at disputes without a conflict of interest: there are 386 questions right now, and you've been involved and received reputation from at least 132 of them (over a third). As a moderator, I hope you'd be less involved in rep-gaining and more involved in the housekeeping aspects of the site.

Comment: +1 Someone who is extremely active will see more issues and thus is more involved with moderation, reputation and badges seems like a good way to show people your activity. Editing and tagging isn't really measure-able though, only by those badges but I don't think anyone has enough for those so far...

Comment: @Mark Trapp: I see where you are coming from, but I would like to think that anyone who is selected as a moderator is able to be passionate about a topic, but separate themselves from their opinions when it comes to taking on the role of moderator.

Comment: @Mark, from my experience, those who don't contribute to content, but only moderate it are **the most terrible moderators**, and do a lot of harm.

Comment: One thing to remember is that this is only temporary moderation.  Mark raises an interesting point, and one that'll probably come up in the actual moderator elections.

Comment: @Mark: I think someone who's really active often makes a really good mod, since they're likely to see problem posts often. I see no problem with it, as long as they're complimented by someone who isn't super-active.

Comment: @Fishtoaster: What Thomas Owens mentioned is what I'm hoping; I wanted to raise the participation level as an issue as something to keep in mind. I'm not saying you should be less active should you become a moderator, but more active in a different aspect of the site.

Answer (score 10):

#### [Thomas Owens](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4/thomas-owens) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/thomas-owens))

I'd be interested in helping this community out. Of all the current Stack Exchanges, this is one of my favorites (the other being Stack Overflow, where [I'm a 20k+ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572/thomas-owens) and have been involved since the early beta). In terms of Area 51 participation (see [my profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/2531/thomas-owens)), I currently have one proposal for a Software Engineering Stack Exchange (currently in the committal phase). In the current public betas, I usually lurk around SEs such as (links go to my profile page) [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/403/thomas-owens), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/91/thomas-owens), [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/110/thomas-owens), and [User Interface](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/343/thomas-owens), since these are areas that I'm somewhat interested in (although don't usually have enough of a background to contribute that much).

Comment: I'll second that

Comment: I really like Thomas as a moderator: he stands on one side of an issue, and can back that stance with justification. And I think a moderator who is pretty hands-off (lurking more than heavy participation) and can view a dispute dispassionately is a great thing.

Answer (score 8):

#### [Lorenzo](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/11/lorenzo) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11/lorenzo))

I'm subjective and argumentative, but (hope) on topic.

Comment: +1 You've been an active and intelligent member since this started.

Comment: @Fishtoaster: thanks.

Comment: you got my upvote ;)

Comment: @systempuntoout, @TomWij: thank you bros!

Comment: @TomWij: this place is rotten. Only aligned thinking is allowed. Like in any dictatorship. In a democratic place would be selected as moderators people with different thinking, not all humble servants...

Answer (score -1):

#### [Chinmay Kanchi](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/61/chinmay-kanchi) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/61/chinmay-kanchi))

I'd like to nominate myself as well. For the most part, I think I fit in well at this community and I participate actively. I'm not super-active at meta, but that's because Fishtoaster seems to beat me to most answers ;). I do read it regularly though, and will throw in an opinion if I think it'll help. I program for a living (well, I'm a PhD student who programs extensively for his project) and I've been programming long enough that I have some understanding of the kinds of things discussed here.

Comment: +1 - I like your answers.

Answer (score -2):

#### [Joe](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/81/joe) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/81/joe))

I'm interested, and would like to nominate myself. I am very interested in helping this site grow, and seeing it become a great place to be on the internet.

I am pretty active in the parent site, and somewhat on meta. Although my rep isn't very high, as of the time of this writing I am on the first page of the users list.

Comment: Not only did someone not think I should do it, but he/she thought I would be a bad one.  Any reason why?

Comment: My issue with your nomination is that your rep is particularly low and you're not very active on Meta: you've provided three answers, one of which is this nomination, and another was down-voted into oblivion. You might make a great candidate for moderator at the end of beta, but you'd need to up your activity, especially on meta.

Answer (score -4):

Why should we do it now?

Does it make sense, if moderators will be selected at the end of some period, maybe public beta stage, or smth, among the persons with high reputation values, maybe even from all SO nestlings family.

Comment: One of the reasons to do it early (though not necessarily this early) is to get the nominee's acceptance.

Comment: Might as well have the question ready.

Comment: Please read this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/. You need to start seeking out candidates for provisional moderators ASAP. The selections are made in about two weeks.

Comment: We should do it now as it is a standard procedure on all the Area 51 betas. The reason is that no one has enough reputation to access moderation tools.

Comment: @Robert - what's the thoughts on people being moderators on two (or more sites)? I'd volunteer as a "backup" moderator if it was thought to be OK.

Comment: @ChrisF: It's possible and it's been done. But all thing being equal, I would rather avoid it. It's not necessarily the workload but having the exposure to a wider range of experiences. But we can look at the situation when the time comes.

Answer (score -4):

#### [Shady M. Najib](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/212/shady-m-najib) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/212/shady-m-najib))

#### Self-nominated

I've been benefiting out of StackOverflow for quite sometime, lately I decided to join to pay back. Though I'm kinda new to Stack Exchange as a whole, You might want to check my profile here & also on [StackOVerFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406464/shady-m-najib), [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/14222/shady-m-najib), I claim I'm very passionate about community

Comment: Just to comment these (-1)s.  Shady, I don't think you're ready to become a moderator.  You're only a member of the SO and StackExchange community for less than a couple of months, and you're yet to discover all quirks of the system we use here.  For example, you asked an old duplicate (http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159/should-we-force-adding-a-coment-with-every-down-vote); this confirms that you're passionate, and we're looking forward to when your passion transforms to understanding.

Comment: @Pavel Shved Thanks for your kind comment, btw, check this reply & tell me if you think this suggestion is more acceptable: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159/should-we-force-adding-a-coment-with-every-down-vote/161#161

Answer (score -5):

#### [Pavel Shved](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/34/pavel-shved) ([meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/34/pavel-shved))

About time someone nominated a person *other than themselves*. So here's why I think Pavel would make a great moderator for Programmers.SE:

- Adept at mocking other users
- Terrible manners
- Unpronounceable name
- Honest about why he shouldn't be a moderator

Comment: I think that's a great success, in just 3 hours I collected as much votes as you!

Comment: @Pavel: obviously, you're as well-suited for the job as I expected!

Comment: A good moderator would not down vote another candidate

Comment: @Pierre, but the *exceptional* moderator surely would!