# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: ChrisF] [image: Fishtoaster] [image: bigown] [image: Walter] [image: Mark Trapp]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods!

Comment: Congratulations Fishtoaster, ChrisF and bigown!

Comment: Congrats ! Please make pse a better place.

Comment: Welcome Walter!

Comment: Welcome Mark Trapp!

Comment: Doesn't contributing to the website involve asking questions?  If a person can't even stick their neck out on the line to ask a few decent questions how can they remotely justify closing everyone else's questions?

Comment: @Peter: Contributing questions and contributing answers are both important. Also, if a person has a good handle on what an appropriate question is, they may be self-censoring, so there's no need to stick their neck out, as you put it. For example, I asked my first question (after subjective guidelines came into effect) today. Up until now I just didn't have much to ask that wasn't already asked by someone else and fit the scope of the site.

Answer (score 6):

**Why bigown?** Nothing against him, but he wasn't even in the [poll](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5)... so I don't understand the logic or the procedure behind that.

Comment: I suppose he has been asked because of his profile on the main site, you should [check it out](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/389/bigown). I guess it's rare for someone to dislike him, and if people are against it... It's all temporary, the elections will give a fair decision.

Comment: I didn't ask to be moderator, but I accepted the indication. I don't know why I were picked, maybe because I ever have P.SE open to monitoring activity. People certainly will hate me soon. Every moderator take unpleasant actions. I don't wanna be candidate on elections.

Comment: I really don't have anything against bigwon, I just whant to know why him, and which is the rationale behind the choice.

Comment: I disagree with bigown on a fair number of things, but so far at least he doesn't seem to be abusing his position (deleting things that he disagrees with or such). As far as not being nominated, that makes him more qualified than most in my opinion - given that nearly all the candidates were self-nominated, nomination doesn't say much.

Comment: @Mr. C - I only self nominated because there was (at the time) only one other nomination. We're only temporary moderators - the "full time" ones will be nominated and voted on when the site leaves beta, so we can have a "better" vote then.

Comment: @ChrisF: not trying to bash you, just saying... all a self-nomination means is that you're willing to participate, which can also be indicated by *participation*. So at this stage (where moderators are chosen by the admins anyway), I'm not particularly concerned about an unsolicited appointment.

Comment: @Mr. C - point taken, but it appears I set a trend which may have upset some people. On the other sites all the mods have come from nominees to the initial thread. I think @bigown is a special case.

Comment: @ChrisF: I agree strongly with every possible meaning for that last sentence.

Answer (score -6):

Remember folks, the best qualification for being appointed moderator is your ability to close questions with extreme prejudice.

Comment: As well as downvote, you've got to have a 3/2 downvote to upvote ratio at least.